# shutdown.sh[3324]: PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current user does not have permission

Tags: permissions, tomcat

I get the following in the journalctl -xe reply after attempting to start tomcat: shutdown.sh[3324]: PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current user does not have permission

Comment: I found the answer.  Needed to change ownership and permissions.  This is Solved